# Slightly complex regex to match a negative look behind followed by an exact phrase

Tags: php, regex, pcre

So I have the following regex:

`(?<!\.)\b([\w\@\-]+) *\b(IN|NOT IN|LIKE|NOT LIKE|BETWEEN|REGEXP|NOT|IS|XOR)+\b *`

which I'm looking to help me match some SQL code.

However, it looks like I'm going to have a problem with the phrases in the second bracket e.g. 'NOT IN' and 'NOT LIKE'

I need a regex that will either match or not match (no partial matches like the way my current regex works).

1. `customers.id NOT IN (SELECT MAX(customers_service.customer_id))` should not match at all
2. `customers.id NOT LIKE (SELECT MAX(customers_service.customer_id))` should not match at all
3. `id NOT IN (SELECT MAX(customers_service.customer_id))` should match
4. `id IN (SELECT MAX(customers_service.customer_id))` should match

I was using RegexBuddy to check and I get matches for No. 1 and No. 2 using my regex.

Also,

1. `id NOT IN (SELECT MAX(customers_service.customer_id))` only matches `id NOT`, as opposed to `id NOT IN`
2. `id NOT LIKE (SELECT MAX(customers_service.customer_id))` only matches `id NOT`, as opposed to `id NOT LIKE`

I'd like to modify this regex to capture the condition of the negative look behind, and also the exact phrases in the second bracket, or match nothing at all (no partials).

How can I get this done?

Comment: Is there no SQL parsing library that you can use that will do a proper job of parsing rather than doing it with regexes?

Comment: Don't parse SQL with RegEx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `\b` does not match the beginning or end of a word.  That's how it's always described, but it's a lie.  What `\b` matches is a position that's *followed* by a word character but not *preceded* by one--`(?=\w)(?<!\w)`--or *preceded* by a word character and not *followed* by one--`(?<=\w)(?!\w)`.  If those conditions are not exactly what you want to match, you're probably better off not using `\b` at all.

The names you're trying to match apparently can contain `@` and `-` as well as the standard "word" characters (letters, digits and underscores), so word boundaries are useless.  In general, to make sure you match a complete word, you would use a negative lookbehind and a negative lookahead:

```
(?<![\w@-])[\w@-]+(?![\w@-])
```

In your case, you also want to make sure the *preceding* character isn't `.`, and you know the *following* character has to be whitespace, so that part of your regex would be:

```
(?<![.\w@-])[\w@-]+\s+
```

The bigger problem is that this can also match things you don't want it to--i.e., keywords like `NOT` and `IN`.  I suggest two remedies.  First, tighten up the regex for the keywords so compound keywords like `NOT IN` and `NOT LIKE` are treated as atomic units:

```
(?:NOT(?:\s+(?:IN|LIKE))?|IN|LIKE|BETWEEN|REGEXP|IS(?:\s+NOT)?|XOR)\b
```

Second, use that in a lookahead to make sure the first word you match is not (part of) a keyword.  Here's the full regex, split into two lines for readability:

```
(?<![.\w@-])(?!(?:NOT(?:\s+(?:IN|LIKE))?|IN|LIKE|BETWEEN|REGEXP|IS|XOR)\b)[\w@-]+\s+
(?:NOT(?:\s+(?:IN|LIKE))?|IN|LIKE|BETWEEN|REGEXP|IS|XOR)\b\s*
```

You can make it easier to maintain by defining a subroutine group for the keywords.  Here's how that might look as a PHP string literal:

```
'~
(?(DEFINE)(?<KEYWORD>
  (?:NOT(?:\s+(?:IN|LIKE))?|IN|LIKE|BETWEEN|REGEXP|IS(?:\s+NOT)?|XOR)\b
))
(?<![.\w@-])(?!(?&KEYWORD))[\w@-]+\s+(?&KEYWORD)\s*
~ix'
```

...and here's a **[demo](http://ideone.com/xM6uOt)**.

Comment: Wow! Thanks Alan! That is one killer regex, and I think I'm going to have to study up on Regular Expressions to get the hang of it all. But it does work. I posted an answer previously which does pretty much the same thing in my testing. So I'm torn as to which to finalize on, maybe the most performant I guess.

Comment: I updated the regex to handle the `IS NOT` keyword and to consume the trailing whitespace like your original regex does.  But I hope you're not doing a lot of this kind of thing.  Regexes are almost completely useless when it comes to SQL; it's a much worse fit than HTML.  Look how difficult it was to perform this extremely limited task!  If the problem had been any more general, I wouldn't even have tried.

Comment: Thanks a lot. No this is for pretty basic sanitization of a very specific SQL query structure. I'm not trying to parse a SQL query with this. Truly, the Regex for this particular task was a real doozy for me but it was the most elegant way to get it done...I'd look at other methods and that would have significantly bloated my code. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Your wording's a bit confusing, but as I understand, the negative lookbehind is working as you'd expect.

For the "partial match" problem, you just have to order your keywords by decreasing length:

```
(?<!\.)\b([\w\@\-]+) *\b(NOT LIKE|BETWEEN|REGEXP|NOT IN|LIKE|NOT|IN|IS|XOR)+\b *
```

This way it attempts to capture "more complete" keywords before settling for shorter ones.

**Edit**

I see what's going on, now. In the case of

```
customers.id NOT IN (SELECT MAX(customers_service.customer_id))
```

the reason there's a match is that `NOT` is being matched by `(?<!\.)\b([\w\@\-]+)`, and `IN` is being matched as the operator. In other words, it thinks `NOT` is a column name.

The only way to get around this is to add a constraint. For example, if you know the string always begins with a table/column identifier, then do this:

```
^\s+([\w\@\-]+) *\b(NOT LIKE|BETWEEN|REGEXP|NOT IN|LIKE|NOT|IN|IS|XOR)+\b *
****
```

No need for a lookbehind nor a word boundary, this way.

If you cannot make that constraint though, then it's tricky, if not completely impractical (since you'd basically have to build an SQL parser out of regex). The key is to give your regular expression some way of distinguishing identifiers from operators; otherwise it can't tell. If you know all your identifiers are lower-case, that might work for your purposes, though flimsy.

Comment: Yes the negative lookbehind works ok, I just have an issue with the phrases. I tried your regex but I still get a match for `customers.id NOT IN `

Comment: Thanks. The tricky bit is that I could have multiple similar occurrences `customers.id NOT IN (SELECT MAX(customers_service.customer_id)) AND customers.id LIKE (SELECT MAX(customers_service.customer_id))`, and also the regex is part of a `preg_replace` script, so I have to match or no match or the replacements are going to get messed up

Answer (score 0):

Ok then. So after much "regexing", here's the regex that did the trick for me:

```
(?<=\s)(?!(?:not|is)(?=\s))([\w\@\-]+)(?=\s) (?<=\s)(NOT LIKE|NOT IN|IS NOT|BETWEEN|REGEXP|LIKE|XOR|NOT|IN|IS)(?=\s)
```

Of course in my `preg` function I would use a case-insensitive pattern modifier.

I had to find the other pieces from other questions I posted here on StackOverflow.

Cheers.